# Wrong icon for image upload button on some sites

Tags: bug, images, help-center, uploader

On some sites, e.g. on SO ["How to formatting"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) help section contains wrong icon for upload an image tool button:

> [image: so]

Here is on MSE image contains [actual version](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting):

> [image: mse]